# Is the matrix totally unimodular?

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization, total-unimodularity

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1&1&0&0&1&0&0\\0&1&0&1&0&0&0&0&0& \\0&0&1&1&1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&-1&-1&0&1&-1&0&0\\0&0&0&-1&0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&-1&-1&0&0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$, is the matrix totally unimodular?

I realised that if I change the order of columns in A I could get  change the matrix I would get  $A=( B I_{6x6})$, but I wasn't sure if I could use this for anything.

Answer (score 0):

Successively applying column-swapping, $C_3 \leftrightarrow C_5$, $C_4 \leftrightarrow C_6$, $C_7 \leftrightarrow C_8$ and $C_8 \leftrightarrow C_9$, we get,

$A^{\prime}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1\\0&1&0&0&0&0&0&1&0& \\0&0&1&0&0&0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&1&0&0&-1&-1&-1\\0&0&0&0&1&0&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&0&0&1&-1&-1&0\end{bmatrix}=\left[I_6 \mid B\right]$, where $B=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\0&1&0& \\1&1&0\\-1&-1&-1\\0&-1&0\\-1&-1&0\end{bmatrix}$

Now, from [here](http://eaton.math.rpi.edu/faculty/Mitchell/courses/matp6620/notesMATP6620/lecture15/15B_TU.pdf), we have

- $A$ is unimodular iff $A^{\prime}$ is unimodular.
- $A^{\prime}$ is unimodular iff $B$ is unimodular.

Now, all remains to be shown is that $B$ is unimodular.

- All elements of $B \in \{-1,0,1\}$
- Any $2 \times 2$ submatrix of $B$ is of the form $\begin{bmatrix}x&x\\ x&x\end{bmatrix}$  or $\begin{bmatrix}x&x\\ -x&-x\end{bmatrix}$ or $\begin{bmatrix}y&0\\ x&x\end{bmatrix}$ or $\begin{bmatrix}0&y\\ x&x\end{bmatrix}$ or $\begin{bmatrix}x&x\\ y&0\end{bmatrix}$ or $\begin{bmatrix}x&x\\ 0&y\end{bmatrix}$ or $\begin{bmatrix}x&y\\ x&0\end{bmatrix}$ or $\begin{bmatrix}y&x\\ 0&x\end{bmatrix}$, or their transpose matrices, where $x,y \in \{-1,0,1\}$, clearly $det(B) = 0$ or $xy \in \{-1,0,1\}$
- Finally, show that all $3 \times 3$ submatrices (there are only ${6 \choose 3} = 20$ of them, each one having all cofactors $\in \{-1,0,1\}$) have determinant $\in \{-1,0,1\}$.

Comment: Since $B=(C , -C)'$ with $C=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\0&1&0\\1&1&0 \end{bmatrix}$ wouldn't it suffice to show that C is totally unimodular?

Comment: But stacking two TU matrices may not produce a TU matrix

Comment: @SandipanDey, I think stacking the same TU matrix or its negative (but only in one direction, either left to right or top to bottom) should always result in a TU matrix by the Ghouila-Houri criterion.

Answer (score 0):

In general stacking TU matrices does not always produce a TU matrix, but in this case I agree that it suffices to show that $C = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1& 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ is TU. We can then get $B$ (defined in the other answer) by adding copies of the rows and then multiplying those rows by $-1$; both operations are easily seen to preserve TU.

For $C$, just note that any $2\times 2$ $(0,1)$-matrix is TU, so it only remains to check the full 3x3-matrix, which is easily done by developing along, say, the third column.